# sbt gen-idea scala version error

Tags: scala, sbt, dependency-management

I receive the following error when running `sbt gen-idea`:

```
[error] {file:/home/jem/projects/app/}default-0df603/*:
update-classifiers: Version specified for dependency 
org.scala-lang#scalap;2.10.0 differs from Scala version in project (2.10.1).
```

Despite this the idea files are still created and seem to work. But I worry that they may be incomplete somehow.

Here is my `build.sbt`:

```
import com.typesafe.startscript.StartScriptPlugin

organization := "com.github.synesso"

name := "app"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.10.1"

seq(webSettings :_*)

classpathTypes ~= (_ + "orbit")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalatra" % "scalatra_2.10" % "2.2.1",
  "org.scalatra" % "scalatra-scalate_2.10" % "2.2.1",
  "org.scalatra" % "scalatra-json_2.10" % "2.2.1",
  "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-server" % "9.0.1.v20130408",
  "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-server" % "9.0.1.v20130408" % "container",
  "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "9.0.1.v20130408",
  "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "9.0.1.v20130408" % "container",
  "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "8.1.7.v20120910" % "container,compile",
  "org.eclipse.jetty.orbit" % "javax.servlet" % "3.0.0.v201112011016" % "container,compile" artifacts Artifact("javax.servlet", "jar", "jar"),
  "org.json4s" % "json4s-jackson_2.10" % "3.2.4",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-simple" % "1.7.5",
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.0.11" % "runtime",
  "com.google.api-client" % "google-api-client" % "1.14.1-beta",
  "com.google.apis" % "google-api-services-plus" % "v1-rev62-1.14.1-beta",
  "com.google.apis" % "google-api-services-oauth2" % "v1-rev33-1.14.1-beta",
  "com.google.http-client" % "google-http-client-jackson2" % "1.14.1-beta"
)

resolvers += "Sonatype OSS Releases" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/"

seq(StartScriptPlugin.startScriptForClassesSettings: _*)
```

I've tried mucking around with different versions of scala and the dependencies, but to no avail. What is going on here? Do I need to fix it? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is controlled by the `checkExplicit` value of the `ivyScala` setting.  You can disable it with:

```
ivyScala ~= { (is: Option[IvyScala]) =>
  for(i <- is) yield
    i.copy(checkExplicit = false)
}
```

I'm surprised that is an error, since I'd normally expect it to be a warning.  Also, this check is no longer on by default in 0.13.

Comment: Ubuntu package manager complained about the deb having "bad quality" when I tried to upgrade, so I used the `ivyScala` code block instead and this worked. Cheers Mark.

Comment: Thanks, I'll follow up with Josh about the bad quality deb.

Comment: Can you let me know what the reason for bad quality was?